# Can an MMU and MPU conflict with each other?

Tags: permissions, arm, mmu, soc

In the AM5K2E02 System-on-Chip, there is an MMU (memory management unit) in the core, and also a peripheral device MPU (memory protection unit).

On other pages, the MMU is described as a superset of MPU, i.e. MMU does everything MPU does and more, but what would happen if both an MMU and MPU are both active?

Reason for asking is we have an MMU configured and setup, but there is an MPU alive with default settings running. Who gets priority when deciding whether such-and-such process or user has access to so-and-so memory region? I can't find a clear answer, and in fact some pages seem to suggest that a SoC will have either MPU or MMU but not both, which isn't true here as the AM5K2E02 has both.

Thanks all :) and merry christmas soon!

Comment: They are at different levels.  From the manual, "KeyStone Architecture Memory Protection Unit (MPU) User's Guide (SPRUGW5)"...  The MMU is built in to all Cortex-A devices.  It is local the CPU complex (SMP).  So caches are other ARM-only accesses will obey/use the MMU.  For most **CODE** this is what matters.  For hardware, the MPU is used.  These look to be BUS protection.  Google 'DMA attack'.  The MPU provides protection at a different level.  The MMU will also take precedence for code as it will be consult first for code access.   But what, if code goes and DMAs to a bonker place? ...

Comment: Priority?  The MMU will prohibit first and the MPU will prohibit 2nd.  The MMU has mapping capabilities.  The MPU has none and is only allow/deny.  The MMU is like a 'redirect/load balancer' and 'firewall' combined.  The MPU is a firewall only.  Accesses must make it through all firewalls.

Comment: Thanks, so if we have fully configured the MMU for our system, then is there any need for the MPU at all? Should we disable it since MPU is redundant?

Comment: If you assume the hardware, drivers and DMA on the system are perfect, then there is no need for this MPU.  It is a common assumption, but would not work for functionally safe systems such as auto, aerospace, etc. You should be able to disable the MPU and enable it later.  Or even use it as a debug feature.  Also, *some pages seem to suggest that a SoC will have either MPU or MMU but not both* is an **ARM MPU**; this is a direct replacement of the MMU with physical addresses and permissions.  The TI "MPU" on this system is different.

Comment: I have categorized [tag:arm-mpu] from the prior [tag:mpu].  Your AM5K2E02 MPU is not the same. You can see the difference from the questions tag [tag:arm-mpu].  The 'TLA' of 'MPU' is over used and causes confusion (for you and the grab bag of questions in the tag [tag:mpu]).